# Harmonic function that extends continuously up to the boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find a harmonic function $u$ in the open first quadrant that extends continuously up to the boundary except at the points $0$ and $1$, and that takes up the following boundary values:

$u(x, y) = 1$ on the half lines $\{y = 0, x > 1\}, \{x = 0, y > 0\}$

$u(x, y) = 0$ on $\{0 < x < 1, y = 0\}$

Quite frankly, I'm not quite sure what the problem is asking... what does it mean for $u$ to extend continuously "up to the boundary, except at the points $0$ and $1$"?

A hint that the problem indicates is that I should find a series of five conformal maps to achieve the goal... but how does this fit into the grand scope of the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is from Stein's Complex Analysis, yes? To be continuous up to the boundary, except at the points $0$ and $1$ means that $u$ is continuous on all of the first quadrant, including the boundary, except the two mentioned points. Namely, this means that you can define values for $u$ on the boundary such that this new "extended function" is still continuous, except at $0$ and $1$. If you have the book, then use Figure 1 on page 213 to help you figure out the conformal maps they mention in Figure 11 on page 250. If you don't have the book, then you could probably find a pdf of it online.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense -- the thing is, the final figure on page 250 (the figure that $F_5$ maps into) doesn't seem to really have anything to do with the conditions on the boundary values... the figure only stipulates that $u = 1$ when $x < 0$, and that $u = 0$ when $x > 0$. How does creating the successive conformal maps precisely let us define our function $u$? Does $u$ become the composition of $F_1 \circ ... \circ F_5$?

Comment: You should read Lemma 1.3 in Chapter 8 and the discussion following it. Also, the hint after the exercise gives you a harmonic function on the upper half-plane satisfying the requirements.

Comment: Is there a specific reason we're defining this function on the upper half-plane? Is this just to make sure that we can hit all of the values on the axis $x = 0$?

Comment: If you look at the points where the function is defined on the upper half place and then follow the conformal map you construct from the upper half place to the first quadrant, the composition of the harmonic function with the conformal map results in a harmonic function with the required boundary conditions.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. So, to summarize: $\frac{1}{\pi}arg(z)$ is harmonic on the upper half-plane, and satisfies the given boundary conditions. We want to find a harmonic function $u$ in the open first quadrant that also satisfies these boundary conditions and extends continuously up to the boundary. Because we can apply a series of conformal maps to the first quadrant and shift it into the upper half plane where our function is indeed harmonic and satisfies the boundary conditions, we know that our $u$ exists in the first quadrant as well. Is that the correct big picture?

Comment: Yup, that is right.